# Duplicate symbol

Tags: iphone

I recently added some openfeint code to my classes and changed them to .mm

All of a sudden I get errors that duplicate symbols are found in the object files when building.

> ld: duplicate symbol _audioPlayer in blah blah /Objects-normal/i386/Stage2.o and /Users/blah blah .build/Debug-iphonesimulator/blah.build/Objects-normal/i386/Stage1.o

Why is it suddenly causing this error? What exactly is the error?

I have variables with the same name in different classes, it should be a problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably declaring two variables with the same name in global scope (not inside interfaces), and the linker is complaining about that.

Answer (score 3):

This error can also occur if you import a .m file instead of .h.

```
#import "SomeClass.m"
```

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you can suppress this error with a command line argument to gcc: 
-Wl,--allow-multiple-definition

Comment: I'm not familiar with XCode, but are you compiling using GCC? If so, its a command line option you would pass it when GCC is invoked on your files.

Comment: You can set this in project/target settings in Other Compiler flags

Answer (score 1):

If you implement your method like  below in .mm file, `duplicate symbol error`will occur.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

class CppTestOne 
{
public:
    void Test();
//    {
//        NSLog(@"Hello C Plus Plus");
//    }
};

void CppTestOne::Test()
{
    NSLog(@"Hello C Plus Plus");
}
```

then you can implement your method by

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

class CppTestOne 
{
public:
    void Test()
    {
        NSLog(@"Hello C Plus Plus");
    }
};

//void CppTestOne::Test()
//{
//    NSLog(@"Hello C Plus Plus");
//}
```

more details for this error not clear